# Python can't find geckodriver in my path

Tags: python, macos, selenium, homebrew

I am fairly new to python and right now, I am currently learning python through Al Sweigart's Automate the boring stuff with Python.

Right now, I want to open a Firefox by using webdriver. When I run the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

I get no error. However, after running:

```
browswer=webdriver.Firefox()
```

I get the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
stdin=PIPE)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver': 'geckodriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
browswer=webdriver.Firefox()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 160, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Now, I have already installed geckodriver and I have been scrolling through google to try to find the solution. So far, I have tried manually adding geckodriver to /usr/local/bin. I have also tried running:

```
brew install geckodriver
```

on terminal. It suggested me to try overwriting geckodriver, so brew installed geckodriver on /usr/local/Cellar/geckodriver/0.21.0/bin/geckodriver.

I've ran

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

to see the list of my paths, and here are the list:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/Cellar/geckodriver/0.21.0/bin/geckodriver
```

So I do not know why python is telling me geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH when it is already there.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Thank you @Ratmir Asanov for the reply. If I uninstall geckodriver, I will go back to square one. 

Does anyone have any idea how to copy geckodriver into my /usr/local/bin file, so I can run without writing down the path everytime?

Comment: "It suggested me to try overwriting geckodriver" What was the exact output of the command?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem as OP on Mac OS.  What solved it for me is to copy geckodriver into the python path.

Specifically in terminal

```
which geckdriver
```

gives the following path

```
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver
```

and

```
which python
```

gives the path for Python

```
/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Then I copied the geckodriver into the python bin

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
cp geckodriver /Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/bin/
```

And I was able to call geckodriver from Python.

Comment: There is a small spelling mistake, shoule be 'which geckodriver'. Saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the geckodriver in the Python folder. I did that when I got the same error and after I place the geckodriver in the Python folder, everything was working. I have included an image as reference. [image: geckodriver in Python folder]

Comment: Note that this question is about macOS while your image is a Windows screenshot.